# Cannot create TEMP table in Android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, temp-tables

I have tried to create a temporary table (sqlite) in Android

Here is the code snippet:

```
// No error - But cannot create TEMP table
database.rawQuery("CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tt1 (unread_message int, target varchar)", null);

// Error - android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tt1: , while compiling: INSERT INTO tt1 SELECT count(*), target  FROM messages where read_status=0 and direction=1 GROUP BY target
database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO tt1 SELECT count(*), target  FROM messages where read_status=0 and direction=1 GROUP BY target", null);
```

There is no error for the create TEMP TABLE query, but it complains tt1 is not existed in the second query. Am I create TEMP table in a wrong way?

Comment: But both queries work in SQLite Manager(Firefox plug-in). I have searched 'SQL scope' and still not ready understand what is 'scope issue'. Can you tell me more about 'scope issue' please? thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be count(target)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically you shouldn't be using `rawQuery` for creating tables and doing inserts - try using `SQLiteDatabase#execSQL`.

This example works at least:

```
    SQLiteOpenHelper dummy = new SQLiteOpenHelper(this, "mobileAppBeginner.db", null, 1) {
        @Override public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
        @Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    };

    SQLiteDatabase db = dummy.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("CREATE TEMP TABLE messages (read_status INTEGER, direction INTEGER, target TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tt1 (unread_message int, target varchar)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tt1 SELECT count(*), target  FROM messages where read_status=0 and direction=1 GROUP BY target");
```

Comment: Can we use this for the Previously Created Database? Actually i have some Tables in my Database and if i need a TEMP table at run time means how can i use. Here i had created a Database Already.

Comment: @gowri did it work ? Can you use it with existing room db ?